# Community Deployment using Metadata API & ExperienceBundles

Tags: community, deployment, metadata-api, force.com-sites, network

We have deployed our community to a sandbox successfully with below components.

```
experiences
navigation menu
sites
Network branding
networks
Content assets
Profiles
Static resources
and other components...
```

But the community is not looking good after the deployment.
Community pages are not assigned with correct custom layouts.

There are some css issues as well.

Is there anything missing from the deployment and configuration?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Also include page layouts per documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323350&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thank you Anudeep... Here the issue was I have deployed Network branding folder and experiences bundle together. We don't need Network branding folder.